# Changing navigation drawer layouts

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to inflate new layout on custom navigation drawer when, for example, I click another button in main activity? Is that possible? I havent found any function like beforeOpenDrawer or etc. Or should I construct 4 seperate drawers?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

We managed that using fragments. Our `DrawerLayout` contains a `FrameLayout` in which we put a "menu" fragment. Some clicks replaces the "menu" fragment by a "submenu" fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you mean.. but if what you want is:

. To create a navigation drawer with custom layout (not just list view) then it is possible.

. Or if you having multiple buttons or radio buttons  inside the drawer layout and you need for example to listen for their onClick events … you only write the code once inside the main activity that inflate the left or right drawer.. I've tried something like that but I was using fragments not activities.

Comment: check this tutorial:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I have created other drawer fragment. The point is, that i need to inflate 4 different layouts depending on button clicks.